# Adding js file to bundle causes error

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

I'm attempting to add jquery scrollTo.js to my bundle using VS 2013.

I've added it to the script manager on the Site.Master

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />                
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="scrollTo.js" Assembly="System.Web"  Path="~/Scripts/scrollTo.js" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

And in BundleConfig.c I've added

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/Scripts").Include(
            "~/Scripts/scrollTo.js"));
```

However when I run the solution I get

```
 Assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' does not contain a Web resource with name 'scrollTo.js'.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're sure the `scrollTo.js` file isn't in `~/Scripts/WebForms/`?

Comment: have you thought about changing the project from .net 4.0 to .net 4.5

Comment: Target framework is .NET 4.5.1  and no the file is in the Scripts directory.

Comment: what about your `BundleConfig.cs` do the entry's match

Comment: I posted that above in the op. AFAICT they match

Answer (score 1):

If you go to your Views > Shared > _Layout.cshtml file, did you add "~@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Scripts")?

Comment: sorry no. it's not mvc. it's webforms.

Comment: Have you tried move the file to the WebForms folder just like what Sam mentioned?  If so, change Path="~/Scripts/scrollTo.js" to Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/scrollTo.js"  (Notice that you're missing the "WebForms" in your Path)

Comment: Minerva I've moved the scrollto.js to the webformsjs bundle and it seems to be working now. scrollto is not working. but that's a different error. thanks.